# Android Room spam to insert records simultaneously is slow

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

When I try to spam a function that wrapped with IO coroutine scope which insert record with Room, the insertion still not able to perform parallelly. Instead it inserts around 3 records at once at the same time then only proceed to the next 2-3 records.
I assume Coroutine would send each function call into a new background thread to run, which will allow the Room insertion to run parallelly?
Are there any advices to optimize this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Well there aren't an infinite number of threads, so surely this behaviour is pretty much expected?

Comment: Note that Room's support for `suspend` insert methods means you don't need to do any manual wrapping at all (Room does that for you).

Comment: try inserting in a single coroutine _inside_ of a transaction

Comment: Because for my application, I need to insert/update large amount of data into my database within a second (which I have to insert one by one instead of bulk), but I realize that every insert/update will be using transaction, and making all the data that suppose to be done within a second become a queuing list of actions which gonna take 10 seconds for example. I'm thinking if this is the limitation of Room, maybe I should change to use realm database instead.